# ${y \in \mathbb{N}}$ but, ${y}$ comes out to be zero, Why?

Tags: linear-algebra

${x \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{K} \gt 0, \mathbb{A} \gt 0}$, Where, ${\mathbb{N}}$ represents 'Natural Numbers', ${\mathbb{A}}$ and ${\mathbb{K}} \in {\mathbb{R}^{+}}$,
Two Equations are given,
$${Equation 1 : \mathbb{K}(x+y) = xy}$$
$${Equation 2 : \mathbb{A}(x-y) = xy}$$
By Using Equation (1) and Equation (2),
$${Equation 3 : \mathbb{K} = \frac{xy}{(x+y)}}$$
$${Equation 4 : \mathbb{A} = \frac{xy}{(x-y)}}$$
Dividing Equation (3) by Equation (4),
$${Equation 5 : \frac{\mathbb{K}}{\mathbb{A}} = \frac{(x-y)}{(x+y)}}$$
Multiplying RHS with (-1) and dividing the same by (-1) must not effect it,
$${\therefore \frac{\mathbb{K}}{\mathbb{A}} = \frac{(x-y)\times(-1)}{(x+y)\times(-1)}}$$
$${\therefore \frac{\mathbb{K}}{\mathbb{A}} = \frac{(x+y)}{(x-y)}}$$
But, by Equation (5),
$${\frac{(x+y)}{(x-y)} = \frac{\mathbb{A}}{\mathbb{K}}}$$
$${\therefore \frac{\mathbb{K}}{\mathbb{A}} = \frac{\mathbb{A}}{\mathbb{K}}}$$
$${Equation 6 : \mathbb{K}^{2} = \mathbb{A}^{2}}$$
Now, By Squaring Equation (1),
$${\mathbb{K}^{2}(x+y)^{2} = x^{2}y^{2}}$$
By Substituting value of ${\mathbb{K}}$ from Equation (6),
$${\therefore \mathbb{A}^{2}(x+y)^{2} = x^{2}y^{2}}$$
As all the variables represent positive numbers, the square root will remain positive,
$${\therefore \mathbb{A}(x+y) = xy}$$
By using Equation (2),
$${\mathbb{A}(x+y) = \mathbb{A}(x-y)}$$
$${\therefore x+y = x-y}$$
$${\therefore y = -y}$$
$${\therefore 2y = 0}$$
$${\therefore y = 0}$$
But, according to the statement, ${y \in \mathbb{N}}$ which is contradictory to the above solution. Why ?

Comment: Your error is in the execution of the step "Multiplying RHS with (-1) and dividing the same by (-1) must not effect it".

Comment: But why, both the (-1) will cancel themselves hence the equation will remain as it is...

Comment: Sure, but you carried it out incorrectly. For example, If you choose to multiply $x-y$ by $-1$, you get $y-x$, not $x+y$. It appears you misapplied the distributive law.

Comment: Okay, I found out my mistake,I went through the solution 2 times and I had not thought it to be a silly mistake!, thanks...

Comment: One final comment. Had you not made an error, and really had shown that $y$ must be $0$, it would just mean that your original equations have no solution in the natural numbers (as you are defining them). When you arrive at a contradiction, it just means that one or more of your original assumptions was wrong. In this case, you started out by assuming that equations 1 and 2 hold for some values $x, y, A, K$. So the contradiction (if it were real) would have meant that no values of $x, y, A, K$ satisfy both equations at the same time.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks I'll take that into mark for future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what $\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{A}, \mathbb{K}$ are since usually they denote sets rather than values.

Also, at the step when you are multiplying by $(-1)$ you have a mistake - it should be $\frac{y-x}{-x-y}$ rather than $\frac{x+y}{x-y}$

Comment: Okay, I found out my mistake,I went through the solution 2 times and I had not thought it to be a silly mistake!, thanks...